# It is possible a software(such as Chrome, games, etc) use multiple internet connection(like IDM does)?

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, isp, throttling

My ISP throttling single connection just use 15 kB/s. So if i play online game(such as Dota 2), streaming youtube, or other thing which use only single connection, it is throttled. Fortunately Internet Download Manager app have feature to make multiple connection for downloading a file, so the speed is incredibly increase. Is there a way(or software) to make all of programs(Google Chrome, etc) in my PC behave like IDM does? use multiple connection for their internet use.. [Picture of IDM use multiple connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcP0Q.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, the application has to specifically programmed to do that, and it has to be compatible with the client-server protocol as well. Not all protocols can be made to work that way.